# Cannot render partial of another module and pass variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I am sorry in advance as I know this should be an easy one but I am stuck. I have a show view for "Category" in which I am trying to display related has_many "Subcategories". I am calling the partial by using the following:

```
<%= render partial: 'subcategories/subcategory', locals: {category: @category }%>
```

I have an html file in the Subcategories view folder properly named and the partial view loads. I know this because the partial has the code

```
<%= @category.name %></p>
```

which shows the correct Category name within the partial. However, when I try to load any of the subcategory data by calling

```
<% @subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
<%= subcategory.name%>
<% end %>
```

I get the error: NoMethodError in Categories#show,  undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

I'm sorry to ask such a basic question but I will be using partials from related modules extensively in this project.

Comment: Where you have define @subcategories ??

Comment: I didn't. Good point. Should I be building a table within the Categories view which lists all the @category.subcategories and then call the partial in each instance?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
 <%= render partial: 'subcategories/subcategory', locals: {category: @category }%>
```

with this:

```
<%= render @category.subcategories %>
```

Then in the partial app/views/subcategories/_subcategory.html.erb do this:

```
<%= subcategory.name %>
```

Comment: That works. I'm not sure how at works quite yet but it does. Sort of. How does it know which partial to render with that call (i.e., _subcategory vs. _form)? Also, how do I take the resulting data and render it in a table? The rendered data comes through as one long string. When I add the table markup it creates unaligned table columns with repeating table heads.

Again, sorry for such basic questions.

Comment: When you ask rails to render an object, rails uses reflection on the object instances name to find the view for it.  So if you have an instance of a truck, the partial will be found in app/views/trucks/_truck.html.erb.  Rails also passes in the object and gives it the same name of the partial.. that's why subcategory.name works

Comment: Great Information! How do I take this content and then structure it in a table format though?

Comment: I gave it a point because while it is correct to a point I found that I needed the original format to pass an array not just one value.

by using the following I was able to create a re-useable table structure on the partial:

    '<%= render :partial => 'subcategories/subcategory', :locals => {subcategories: @category.subcategories} %>'